# Plugin of wordpress cannot update css?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I update a file style of plugin **[The Post Grid](https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-post-grid/)**

```
.rt-tpg-container .layout2 .rt-holder {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

whenever when i reload page and review style of it. It's not change and F12 to show style:

```
.rt-tpg-container .layout2 .rt-holder {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Comment: can u just check CSS file of new code whether it link properly or not to that page?

Comment: Are you update this CSS in your `style.css`? Note: your custom style file should be load final. And add: `!important` before property you want to change.

Answer (score -2):

Add the css in you r current activated theme `style.css` file